# Modify nested struct column and concat string to same column in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I have this below schema

```
root
|-- Item: struct
|    |-- SK: struct
|    |    |-- N: string
```

I want to modify the 'N' to 'S'.
Typically a value in the Item would be a two level nested `{{123},{abc},....{},{}}`
I want to concatenate a custom string to 123 and my final output should look like the below `{{xyz123},{abc},....{},{}}`

I have tried with `df.withColumn` and `df.select` and tried using `withField` but no luck.